# AWS EMR - on which port Hue works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr, hue

How to enable Hue to be accessible from outside network on AWS EMR?
(e.g. from my computer)

Also - what is recommended secured way to authenticate with EMR/Hue?

Comment: [Connecting to the Hue Web User Interface - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/accessing-hue.html)

Comment: Hue has multiple ways to authenticate. OAuth might be the most secured

Comment: Any more info on OAuth and how to setup?